# Android RSA encryption with OAEP using SHA-256 for main and MGF1 digests

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, rsa

By specification I need to use "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding" cipher with SHA-256 for both digests - the main digest and the MGF1 digest.

[Android Cryptography](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography) suggests to initialize `Cipher` like this: `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));`
In reality this is not working, because `init(DECRYPT_MODE, ...)` throws exception: `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported`.

Do anyone know, how to resolve this problem? Using another algorithm parameters in no option.

This is the code sample, run `encryptDecrypt()` to reproduce the error. Minimum api level is 23.

```
static void encryptDecrypt()
{
    KeyPair keyPair = generateWrappingKeypair("MY_KEY");
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
        byte[] data = new byte[1]; // Just create the smallest data to encrypt

        // Encryption goes well
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(new byte[1]);

        // This line throws exception: "InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported"
        cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        if (!Arrays.equals(data, decrypted))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Decrypted data is not equals to raw data");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Encryption error, exception: " + ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

static KeyPair generateWrappingKeypair(String aliasOfKey)
{
    Calendar dateValidFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar dateValidTo = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateValidTo.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    KeyGenParameterSpec specOfKey = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(aliasOfKey, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(4096, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F0))
            .setKeySize(4096)
            .setKeyValidityStart(dateValidFrom.getTime())
            .setKeyValidityEnd(dateValidTo.getTime())
            .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
            .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal(String.format("CN=%s", aliasOfKey)))
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256) // Setting two SHA256 digests here don't make any difference
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
            .build();

    try
    {
        KeyPairGenerator generatorOfKeyPairs = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        generatorOfKeyPairs.initialize(specOfKey);
        return generatorOfKeyPairs.generateKeyPair();
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot generate keypair, exception: " + ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

static Cipher getCipher(int operationMode, Key key) throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    // AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround should be used here from API 23 for Cipher to be compatible with AndroidKeyStore keys
    // Any other security provider is not compatible
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding", "AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround");
    cipher.init(operationMode, key, new OAEPParameterSpec(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));

    return cipher;
}
```

Comment: Does `"NoPadding"` work?

Comment: No. And it is no option, because I need cipher with OAEP padding.

Comment: Well, you can of course add the padding yourself if you don't use the Android key store. However, if you want to decrypt then your private key cannot be in the Android key store. If raw decrypt (`"NoPadding"`) is available then you could remove the padding course, which is why I was asking. Currently the solution space looks empty.

Comment: did you get solution for above problem?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution. There is a workaround. Use 3rd party library to encrypt/decrypt with SHA-256 digest. The private key for these operations is stored in AndroidKeystore with SHA-1 digest. The downsides - twice as long operation, and exposure of private key in memory.