# Android strongbox backed keys cannot be used for RSA encryption

Tags: android, rsa

I've been playing with the new Android Strongbox backed keys on a Pixel 3a, and I've encountered an issue where keys that are backed by Android Strongbox cannot be used with RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding where SHA256 is used as the digest.

All the primitives in question should work with Strongbox, so I'm a bit stumped.

```
    /**
     * Generates an 2048 bit RSA keypair
     */
    private fun generateRsaKeypair(alias: String, isStrongboxBacked: Boolean): KeyPair {
        val keyGenParameterSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT)
            .run {
                setIsStrongBoxBacked(isStrongboxBacked)
                setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
                setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                build()
            }
        val keypair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore").let {
            it.initialize(keyGenParameterSpec)
            it.genKeyPair()
        }

        return keypair;
    }

    /**
     * Tests that a short array of 32 bytes can be encrypted and recovered
     */
    @Test
    fun canRsaRoundtrip() {
        val encAlgo = "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding"
        val decAlgo =  encAlgo
        val wrappingKey = generateRsaKeypair("roundtrip", isStrongboxBacked = true)

        val input = ByteArray(32)

        val spec = OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)

        val encCipher = Cipher.getInstance(encAlgo)
        encCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, wrappingKey.public, spec)
        val ciphertext = encCipher.doFinal(input)

        val decCipher = Cipher.getInstance(decAlgo)
        decCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, wrappingKey.private, spec)

        // Throws android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
        val cleartext = decCipher.doFinal(ciphertext)
    }
```

The exception thrown is:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:519)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
    at com.minimumreproducible.KeyWrapperTest.canRsaRoundtrip(KeyWrapperTest.kt:204)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2196)

Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
    at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1303)
    at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
    at com.minimumreproducible.KeyWrapperTest.canRsaRoundtrip(KeyWrapperTest.kt:204)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2196)
```

- If I change `isStrongboxBacked` to false then the test passes.
- If I change `OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)` to `OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)` then it passes regardless of isStrongboxBacked.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Obviously `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1` uses SHA1, not SHA-256. So why not use `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk This would throw `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported`

I'm coding to a specification, so I need to get the given parameter spec working with isStrongboxBacked = true

Comment: The android documentation says it was added in API level 1, i.e. it's been available since the beginning. Also, what happens if you add SHA1 to the list of acceptable digests in the `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder`? There's even an example of its use [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography#kotlin).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I guess that's not supported for whatever reason by any of the available providers, at least on Android 10. There are [other SO questions about using SHA256 for the MGF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311789)/android-rsa-encryption-with-oaep-using-sha-256-for-main-and-mgf1-digests), but regardless, it's not what I'm trying to achieve. The particular arrangement (RSA-OAEP mode, SHA-256 digest, SHA-1 MGF1 digest) is required by the interface I'm coding against.
Adding SHA 1 to the digests has no effect.

Comment: You said "cannot be used" but you never explained what that means. What happens if you try to use `AEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)`? If there is an exception thrown then please copy and paste the full exception, don't hand-type a little blurp from it. This behavior if true seems like a bug.

Comment: Btw the reason that we can't use SHA256 as the MGF is that [AndroidKeyStoreRsaCipherSpi.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d23dc50/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi.java#307) explicitly prevents it

Comment: Seems to clearly be a bug to me. Is there any documentation on this?